# In nvim, how can I I make it so the mouse will select a split, but not select any text. I only want the mouse to control window focus

Tags: vim, neovim, vim-plugin, nvim-lspconfig

I want to be able to toggle on and off this potential feature too. Sometimes, I don't want to change the cursor position, but I want to use my mouse to select a split to focus on.

I tried disabling mouse and fiddling with in by typing `:h mouse` in nvim, but nothing I could find in the docks helped

Comment: `:h mouse` may help you